# WooCommerce REST API - how to upload images that have url with ID rather than file extension

Tags: rest, woocommerce

WC API documentation suggests that image references in the JSON body should be absolute paths to images with a file extension. ie: (warning, bear alert) : https://www.southhavenjellystone.com/content/uploads/yogi-emergency.jpg

However, I want to upload a valid image using a url that has a query with parameters ie :
https://996356.app.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=1022936&c=996356&h=b3579ce7d2680de37931

in my WC JSON I pass the following snippet:

```
 "images": [
        {
            "src": "https://996356.app.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=1022936&c=996356&h=b3579ce7d2680de37931"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://www.southhavenjellystone.com/content/uploads/yogi-emergency.jpg"
        }
    ]
```

I know that I may have to add some kind of extension that grabs the actual URL of the image, and passes it instead of the dynamic address.
But I have no idea how or where to implement this.

I do understand that this function can grab the url of an image attachment, but I believe that this is only after an image has been uploaded.

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' );
```

I just need to turn the dynamic image reference into an absolute path of the image.
Can anyone help?

Cheers

Comment: Did you found any solution ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72687571